# Run php script with AJAX and POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm quite new to AJAX. I did some of them with javascript that returns HTML, but I'm struggling with something that I think should be really simple.

I have a header with an inline element:

```
<header>
  <span class="right_alignment">
    <a id="delete_work" href="">
      <input id ="work_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $work_id ?>"/>
      <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">
      </i>
    </a>
  </span>
</header>
```

I want to send $work_id to a PHP script that executes a MySQL query that deletes this record in the database. It has to be a POST request, and as it is an inline element I can't use a form. So AJAX is the way. This is my try:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#delete_work").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'scripts/script-delete-work.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $('#work_id').val(),
    });
  });
});
```

For now script-delete-work.php don't worry me, so is as simple as:

```
$edition_id = $_POST['work_id'];
echo $work_id;
```

But this setup doesn't work. I know that it is the simplest form of an AJAX, but I can't figure how to send the data or what is failing. Any help?

Thanks!

EDIT --
Ok, I solved the data thing. What I have now is:

HTML

```
<span class="span_edit_right">
  <a id="delete_work" href="">
    <input id="work_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $work_id; ?>"/>
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true">
        </i>
  </a>
</span>
```

Script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#delete_work").click(function () {
    var val = $('#work_id').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'scripts/script-delete-work.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { "work_id" : val },
      success: function ()
      {
        alert("works!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php echo $_POST['work_id'];
```

When I click on `#delete_work` it returns the alert `"works"`, and reload the page, but doesn't show the page with `<?php echo $_POST['work_id'];`.

Comment: Check the answer below please. Might be helpful.

Comment: Try `data: {work_id: $('#work_id').val()}` and get `$_POST['work_id']` in php script.

Comment: add tihs `alert(val);` after `var val = $('#work_id').val();` , findout variable has value or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code please

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#delete_work").click(function () {
    var val = $('#work_id').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'scripts/script-delete-work.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { "work_id" : val },
      success: function () 
      {

      }

    });
  });
});
```

And on your server side just

```
echo $_POST['work_id'];
```

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with all this. But still doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

The problem is apparently that with AJAX you are not going to be sent to another PHP page, so I couldn't see the `echo $_POST['work_id'];`. But now it works, it was the data problem…

Actual code is:

```
<span class="span_edit_right">
    <a id="delete_work" href="">
        <input id="work_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $work_id; ?>"/>
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true">
        </i>
    </a>
</span>
```

Script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#delete_work").click(function () {
    var val = $('#work_id').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'scripts/script-delete-work.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { "work_id" : val },
      success: function ()
      {
        alert("works!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look to my powerful upvote which costs +100 points everywhere. I am a superman !

Answer (score 0):

use the ajax success function. and return $edition_id instead of work_id

success: function(work_id)

Comment: Don't you think providing an example would make this answer worthy of posting? So far this is more like a comment than a given solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that you don't get the value of the checked box.

You forgot `;` in `value="<?php echo $work_id; ?>"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending data correctly. You should pass data in javascript object form i.e **{'parameter_name':parameter_value}** so below is the code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#delete_work").click(function () {
    var wrkId = $('#work_id').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'scripts/script-delete-work.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'work_id':wrkId},
    });
  });
});
```

**Or**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#delete_work").click(function () {
    var wrkId = $('#work_id').val();
    $.post('scripts/script-delete-work.php',{'work_id':wrkId},function(response){
    console.log(response);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: okay right click and click on inspect element and click on console tab and see if there any js errors. so that we could get the solution.  i just updated my answer maybe another one will work for you